# How to measure the width of view in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I am having two text views in Linear layout having horizontal orientation. Width of text views are wrap_content. If the sum of width of two text views is less than the screen width it is fine. If the sum of width exceeds the screen width then i need to change the orientation from horizontal to vertical.

I tried using getWidth() in onCreate of the activity but it returned 0. I can try creating a custom view with onSizeChanged() function but i am using two text views so i am not sure that when onSizeChanged() in one text view will not make sure that the other textview is fully drawn to get the width. Any suggestions is really helpful for me.

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/status_container"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"> 
    <TextView android:id="@+id/view1" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/view2"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>

// In OnCreate() function
TextView view1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.view1);
TextView view2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.view2);
view1.setText("Good Morning,");
view2.setText("I am Ron");
int view1_width = view1.getWidth();
int view2_width = view2.getWidth();
if ((view1_width + view2_width) > screen_width) {
     // Change the Linear Layout orientation to Vertical
}
```

Here view1_width and view2_width are returning 0. I want to check if the view1_width + view2_width is greater than the screen width then i need to change the orientation into vertical, or else Horizontal orientation is fine.

-Ron

Comment: what is the objective? weight="1" for both will get you two element with ~half the screen each

Comment: Could you post the code that you have in onCreate()?

Comment: you can't user getWidth() in onCreate() as the GUI doesn't exist yet. Try it in onStart()

Comment: @njzk2 the objective is to get the width of two textviews are runtime and i need to check whether the width is more than the screen size if so change the textviews to align vertically. "AT-Daniel" I have edited the question and posted the snippet "AT-Vicki" I tried using in onStart() but how can i make sure that both the text views are rendered so that the width given by getWidth() is proper for both the text boxes. Also thanks everyone for the response.

Comment: so it would be some sort of FlowLayout. This may help http://nishantvnair.wordpress.com/2010/09/28/flowlayout-in-android/

Comment: Maybe this might help you. textview.getPaint().measureText(text) _ gives the size for the textview for a certain text.

Comment: The last comment solved the issue. Now by using the getPaint.measureText(Text) i am able to get the size of the textview. Thanks for the Info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your activity's onCreate

```
ViewTreeObserver vto = layout.getViewTreeObserver();
     vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
         @Override
             public void onGlobalLayout() {
                 //You should be able to get the width and height over here.

                 layout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
             }
     });
```